# Regex to match IP addresses but ignore localhost

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, regex-negation

So I have this script that does something with IPs allocated to my OS (GNU/Linux) that I get from running `ifconfig`. It works fine, however, I was wondering if I could filter out loopback/localhost IP (127.0.0.1) in the same regex expression [I assume every server within my cluster has said IP and I don't need to do anything with it in my script.]

What my script uses  is:

```
ifconfig | awk '/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3})/ {print}' |sed -e "s/.*addr\://g" -e "s/\s.*//g"
```

I get results like:

```
> ifconfig | awk '/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3})/ {print}' |sed -e "s/.*addr\://g" -e "s/\s.*//g"
172.16.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

I know it might be a stupid question, but could I filter any IP that starts with 127 in my first regex?

I could try changing awk for grep, somethin like:

```
> ifconfig |egrep -o "addr\:(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})" |sed -e "s/.*addr\://g"
```

but if I try to negate (?!127) at the beginning, bash will interpret it as !127 which would just throw me something from the history.

I mean, I could just run another grep at the end of the oneliner like `grep -v "127.0.0.1"`, but I  just wanted to avoid greping something already greped. Not that anything is wrong with that, just trying to know  little more and be more efficient, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only one grep without sed or awk:

```
# ip a|grep -oP "inet \K[0-9.]*(?=.*[^ ][^l][^o]$)"
192.168.1.31
172.16.5.31
```

Comment: That's even better

Comment: Just to clarify, basically you are just filtering what ends with `lo`, correct?. If you take out the `[^l]`it'll also work, as very unlikely you will have an interface that ends with a letter. But as it is, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a clause to match the `127.0.0.1` and exclude it by adding the `next` as below. This way `Awk` ignores doing any action on the lines containing this pattern.

```
.. | awk '/127.0.0.1/{next}/(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3})/{print}' | ..
```

Comment: yahh! I knew it was something easier than I thought. Thank you Sr.